# Program for Password in C++

Tags: c++

Password program not working....pls help....for right input also it says wrong password

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h> 
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream.h>

void main()
{  
  clrscr();
  int ctr=0;
  int  o;
  char pass[5];

  cout<<"enter password";
  for(int i=0;i<5 && (o=getch())!=13  ;i++)
  {  
    pass[i]=o;

    putch('*');
  }

  ctr=strcmp(pass,"luck");
  cout<<ctr;
  if(ctr==0)
  {
    cout<<"welcome";
  }
  else
  {
    cout<<"wrong password";
  }
  getch();
}
```

I want to know why this password program not working....is their any other way

Comment: The `strcmp` function is for C-style strings only, not arrays of characters. The documentation is clear, "compares two [**strings**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling)".

Answer (score 6):

To be able to use `strcmp()`, you need to NUL-terminate `pass`. You also need to make sure that `pass` is large enough to accommodate the NUL.

Comment: ...and, pass[] needs to be large enough to accommodate the \0 as well.

Comment: It means you don't understand what a string is. [Start here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling).

Comment: when i am using strcmp then if the password enter is correct then ctr value should be zero....but its not zero

Comment: @rahulyadav See Davids comment immediately above yours, immediately above mine.

Comment: @rahulyadav: You shouldn't be using `strcmp` because that compares **strings**. The password entered is an array of characters, not a string. So *strcmp* gives a meaningless answer.

Comment: @rahulyadav: You can make a function to compare character-by-character if you want. You can use `strncmp`. You can make the entered data into a C-style string. The important thing is to understand what you're doing, what the functions you are calling do, and why it's not working, that is far more important than changing things until it works.

Comment: if i enter something it goes into a which from the loop goes to string 'pass'....when the full password is entered then i m comparing it with luck which is my predefined password....i cant understand whats wrong with that

Comment: @rahulyadav: `pass` is just an array of characters. It doesn't follow the rules for a C-style string. Please read the link I gave you. (How would `strcmp` know how many characters to compare?)

Answer (score 0):

As `<conio.h>` is in use, I'm assuming Windows is being used. For those who are interested, here is a start on the proper way to do this. I input a line as the password, ending when enter is pressed, and don't show asterisks, as they give away the length pretty easily.

```
//stop echoing input completely
HANDLE inHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); //get handle to input buffer
DWORD mode; //holds the console mode
GetConsoleMode(inHandle, &mode); //get the current console mode
SetConsoleMode(inHandle, mode & ~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT); //disable echoing input

//read the password
std::string password; //holds our password
std::getline(std::cin, password); //reads a line from standard input to password

//compare it with the correct password
std::cout << (password == "luck" ? "Correct!\n" : "Wrong!\n"); //output result

//return console to original state
SetConsoleMode(inHandle, mode); //set the mode back to what it was when we got it
```

Of course there are things you can do to improve it (a hardcoded password string is never a good thing), and go ahead and do so if you wish, but the point is that it works as a basic password input system and has an easy-to-follow structure. You can still use the things you love when getting a password input, rather than going one character at a time and resorting to C strings and code.

Comment: Hello chris.....the things used here would be defiantly work but i am not aware of the things used here like SetConsoleMode and things like that....i dont know what pointers are

Comment: @rahulyadav, Well, the only pointers used here are the one obscured by the `HANDLE` type (really just a `void *`), and the passing of `mode` to `GetConsoleMode`, which allows the function to set `mode` to the correct value. These functions are all ready for use after including `<windows.h>`. For starters, here's the [documentation on `SetConsoleMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @rahulyadav, Well, it's probably best to go through a book on C++ first, before doing platform-specific stuff. To use the Windows API, for example, knowledge of pointers is a big must, along with many other features of the language. It's a spiky pit of death that's waiting for you to slip and fall in, so it's best not to go near it until you're ready.